# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. in assigning strings

Tags: matlab

I am trying to assign string into matlab zeros.

```
a = zeros(10);
a(1,:) = 'Hand';
```

But, I am getting the following error.

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

I got the meaning of error. But I am trying to assign 'Hand' - which is of length 4. But I have 10*10 array.

Any help is appreciable

Comment: MATLAB introduced a [`String` class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) in R2016b. Before this, strings are treated as arrays of characters, which comes with the same dimensionality restrictions as numeric arrays.

Comment: a(1,1:4) = 'Hand';  
it's getting stored as ASCII value ? can it be as just string ? Coz when I try to access it again, I want them as strings.

Comment: The problem is that I am storing it as a mat file. when i try to load the mat file, I am getting 4 dimensional ascii values and not strings

Comment: I don't see that mentioned anywhere in your question. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string has length 4, but the place you're trying to assign it to has length 10, so that  is why you're getting the error. (You can check the dimensions using `size()`) Try

```
a(1,1:4) = 'Hand';
```

Comment: it's getting stored as ASCII value ? can it be as just string ? Coz when I try to access it again, I want them as strings.

Comment: @KathiravanNatarajan Access it using `char(a(1,1:4))`